# How to make a query that computes the difference of two timefield objects/attributes in Django?

Tags: sql, django, database

Suppose I have a model that has four attributes:

- *name*,
- *time in*,
- *time out*,
- *date*.

*time in* and *time out* are **timefield** objects. Now, I want to write a django query that tells me **who was available in the office for most time duration in a given range.**

I am not sure how do I calculate the time difference (time out - time in) on the fly. Do I need to put another attribute like time duration? I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: You question is [suspiciously similar to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39213525/django-query-how-do-i-find-the-maximum-time-duration-from-start-and-end-time-f). Homework assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible using vanilla Django ORM.

Two solutions come to my mind:

1. Fetch the results in RAM and do the computation.
2. Add a new field to take care of the [duration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#durationfield) into your model. You can first do an update query to calculate the duration for all rows in your db.

   Class.objects.update(duration=F('time_out')-F('time_in'))

And then you can `order_by` duration and get the first entry as your max duration.